# In Ruby, MongoDB returns a BSON::OrderedHash. How to I convert it to JSON? Using to_json gives a "stack level too deep" error

Tags: ruby, json, mongodb

I am trying to make a web service using Ruby Sinatra and MongoDB. It will return JSON objects. I decided to use MongoDB, in part, because it stores documents internally in a "JSON-like" structure. I thought this would make it easy to me to run a query and send a JSON result to the client. However, I have run into problems converting the results from MongoDB into JSON.

MongoDB's find_one() returns a BSON::OrderedHash. From the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.0.2/BSON/OrderedHash.html) it seems like this should behave similar to Ruby's Hash type. When I try to convert it to JSON using the .to_json function, I get a "stack level too deep" error. Trying to convert an identical works just fine.

This code works like I would expect:

```
require "json"

my_hash = Hash.new
my_hash[ "a" ] = "aaa"
my_hash[ "b" ] = 9

puts my_hash.to_json
```

This code produces `to_json': stack level too deep (SystemStackError):

```
require "json"
require "bson"

my_bson = BSON::OrderedHash.new
my_bson[ "a" ] = "aaa"
my_bson[ "b" ] = 9

puts my_bson.to_json
```

Trying to convert to hash first didn't help. Same error.

```
puts my_bson.to_hash.to_json
```

Why am I getting the stack level too deep error? This is a simple hash. Is there an easy to to convert the MongoDB results to JSON? I don't want to write a conversion function that is specific to my data. That defeats the point of have a schemaless database.

Comment: Heh. At first I thought "BSON" in the title was a typo. Learn something new every day.

Comment: Your examples are working with my current setup in irb. I have ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux], irb 0.9.5(05/04/13), bson (1.0.1), bson_ext (1.0.1). Does the error with normal bsons or only with the ones gotten from a MongoDB database?

Comment: I have not been able to get bson_ext to build on my system so I am just using bson. It is possible for you to try without bson_ext? Maybe that accounts for the difference?

Does anyone know if there is a windows binary version of bson_ext available somewhere so I can avoid the pain of trying to get it to build?

Comment: No harm leaving this question visible seeing it has some up votes and the answer might be helpful so someone some day.

Answer (score 3):

Try this workaround:

```
class BSON::OrderedHash
  def to_h
    inject({}) { |acc, element| k,v = element; acc[k] = (if v.class == BSON::OrderedHash then v.to_h else v end); acc }
  end

  def to_json
    to_h.to_json
  end
end
```